# SAS - Missing value replacement "." by 0 for numeric but not for date

Tags: arrays, macros, sas

I have a SAS macro:

```
%MACRO missing_values (ds);
    DATA &ds. (drop=_i);
        SET &ds. ;
        ARRAY A_VarNum[*] _NUMERIC_;
        DO _i = 1 TO dim(A_VarNum);
            IF A_VarNum (_i)=. THEN A_VarNum (_i)=0 ;
        END;
    RUN;
%MEND;
```

which replaces `.` by `0`, but I would like that dates stay the way they are, so that they are not replaced by 01/01/1960.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do your date variables have a specific format? If so, you can use VFORMAT() to identify the variables and skip them in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you never expect to encounter 1st January 1960 in your date variable, another option would be to define a custom date format that displays missing values for that date, e.g.

```
proc format;
 value mydate
  low--1 = [yymmdd10.]
   0     = '.'
   1-high= [yymmdd10.]
   ;
run;

data _null_;
 format datevar mydate10.;
 do datevar = -1,0, 24000;
  put datevar=;
 end;
run;
```

Output:

```
 datevar=1959-12-31
 datevar=.
 datevar=2025-09-16
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the date variables have a format assigned to them? Are they all the same?
In that case you could check for the formatted value '01/01/1960' using the `VVALUE` function and change the values back to missing.
Not very efficient, but SAS is not very good at checking for dates.

```
data test;
format e ddmmyy10.;
    do i = 1 to 10;
     e = .;
     f =.;
     output;
    end;
run;

%MACRO missing_values (ds);
    DATA &ds. (drop=_i);
        SET &ds. ;
        ARRAY A_VarNum[*] _NUMERIC_;
        DO _i = 1 TO dim(A_VarNum);
            IF A_VarNum (_i)=. THEN DO;
                A_VarNum (_i)=0;
                IF VVALUE(A_VarNum (_i))='01/01/1960' THEN A_VarNum (_i)=.;
            END ;
        END;
    RUN;
%MEND;
%missing_values(test);
```